# EGit out of sync

Tags: git, versioning, egit

I had a small crash but had all the data in safe storage. But now when I try to open my workspace EGit doesn't seems to have got a little bit out of sync.
Icons are simply put not correct.
A lot of files are marked with as dirty "`>`" and a few as staged "`*`" whatever that means...

Is there a way to get files into sync with my local repository again?

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a full refresh is not enough, then an extreme solution would be to:

- delete the project (only from the workspace, not from the disk)
- re-import the project in the workspace

, and see if the EGit still shown incoherences with the files status.

---

Note: see [label decorations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Icon_Decorations):

[image]

> - **dirty** (`>`) - The resource has changes in the working tree that are neither in the index nor in the repository.
> - **staged** (`*`) - The resource has changes which have been added to the index. Note that adding changes to the index is currently possible only in the commit dialog via the context menu of a resource.
> - **partially-staged** (`*>`) - The resource has changes which are added to the index and additional changes in the working tree that neither reached the index nor have been committed to the repository.